# Foundation 6 -- Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I've been working on a web project using Foundation 6 (specifically, the starter theme [FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress)).

All of a sudden, I get the error outlined in the title when gulp was watching and compiling my scss file -- one called, "_front.scss".

Here's the error:

```
[08:46:21] gulp-notify: [Sass Error] assets/scss/templates/_front.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
    on line 210 of assets/scss/templates/_front.scss
>> }
   ^
```

Here's the code in _front.scss that generated the error:

https://gist.github.com/jarrydfillmore/60172b5530b974c621b7ce07169ac65b

There's no spaces or anything after the last line, which happens to be on line 210.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: A quick search reveals that the code has 59 opening brackets and 60 closing brackets. There's a mismatch somewhere, just go through it carefully and match all opening brackets to closing brackets. Proper indentation would help here.

Comment: Thanks @Juhana. How did you figured out there were 59 opening and 60 closing brackets?

Comment: On Chrome, ctrl-F, search for { and then for }. It shows how many matches it finds. Any text editor should have a similar feature.

Comment: Thank you @Juhana, I'll start there. Appreciate it.